# Create recommendation system from values in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create a recommendation system in Django where I get the user with the highest `rating`. The rating is linked to the user as a `Foreign-Key` as seen in the code below:

**models.py**

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        ProjectOrder, default="null", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    made_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default="null",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    assign = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title + " - " + self.made_by.username

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']


class Rating(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[
                                    MaxValueValidator(5),
                                    MinValueValidator(0),
                                ])
    review = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                          blank=True, 
                                          null=True, 
                                          related_name="reviewed_by")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

**Template**

```
{% for bid in client_bids_assign %}
        <div
          class="p-2 my-2 d-fle"
          style="
            border-radius: 10px;
            gap: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0.5px 2px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.651);
          "
        >
          <small id="">
            <p class="badge bg-info">{{ bid.made_by }}</p>
            <!-- star rating -->
            <fieldset class="starability-result mx-auto" data-rating="{{rating}}">
              Rated: {{rating}} stars
            </fieldset>
            <p class="text-muted">{{ bid.date }}</p>
          </small>
          <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="d-none">
              <input type="text" name="bidId" id="bidId" value="{{ bid.id }}" />
            </fieldset>
            {% if bid.assign is False %}
            <button
              class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"
              type="submit"
              value="{{ bid.id }}"
            >
              Assign <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            </button>
            {% else %}
            <button
              class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"
              type="submit"
              value="{{ bid.id }}"
            >
              Un-assign <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            </button>
            {% endif %}
          </form>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I am using a class based view therefore, this is how I get the rating.
this is a `DetailView` that handles a POST request and some other functionalities.

**Views.py**

```
class ProjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = ProjectOrder
    
    #....
    def test_func(self):
        usergroup = None
        usergroup = self.request.user.groups.values_list(
            'name', flat=True).first()
        if usergroup == "Writers" or usergroup == "Admin" or usergroup == "Clients":
            return True
        return False

    # Get detail template according to user.
    def get_template_names(self):
        usergroup = None
        usergroup = self.request.user.groups.values_list(
            'name', flat=True).first()
        if usergroup == "Writers":
            return ["writer/projectorder_detail.html"]
        elif usergroup == "Clients" or usergroup == "Admin":
            return ["client/projectorder_detail.html"]
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("You are not allowed to access this page")
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        client_bids = Bid.objects.filter(project__id=project.id)
        client_bids_assign = Bid.objects.filter(
            project__id=project.id, assign=True)
        
        #get the rating of the user from the bid
        def get_rating():
            for bid in client_bids_assign:
                user = bid.made_by #this user need to come from the bid inside the loop on the template
                rating = user.rating_set.all()

                agg = 0
                count = 0
                for rating in rating:
                    agg = agg + rating.score
                    count += 1
                    rating = agg/count
                return rating

        context.update({
            'bForm': BidForm,
            'client_bids': client_bids,
            'client_bids_assign': client_bids_assign,
            'rating': get_rating()
        })

        return context

    # Post request handler (Bid form)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        bform = BidForm(request.POST)

        # bidForm section
        if bform.is_valid():
            project = self.get_object()
            bids = project.bid_set.all()

            if bids.exists():
                for bid in bids:
                    if bid.made_by == request.user:
                        bid.delete()
                        messages.info(request, "Bid reverted successfully")
                    else:
                        try:
                            new_bform = bform.save(commit=False)
                            new_bform.project = self.get_object()
                            new_bform.made_by = self.request.user
                            new_bform.save()

                            messages.success(
                                request, "Your bid has been submitted successfully")
                        except:
                            messages.error(
                                request, "Bid sending error, Try again later")
            else:
                try:
                    new_bform = bform.save(commit=False)
                    new_bform.project = self.get_object()
                    new_bform.made_by = self.request.user
                    new_bform.save()

                    messages.success(
                        request, "Your bid has been submitted successfully")
                except:
                    messages.error(
                        request, "Bid sending error, Try again later")

        context.update({
            'bForm': BidForm,
            'client_bids': client_bids,
            'client_bids_assign': client_bids_assign,
            'rating': get_rating()
        })
        # check usergroup to return appropriate page client/writer
        if usergroup == "Writers":
            return render(request, "writer/projectorder_detail.html", context)
        else:
            return render(request, "client/projectorder_detail.html", context)
```

my problem is that I can't seem to be able to get the user that submitted the bid from the template to be the user in the view whose rating I want to get. I have also tried having the mathematical operations in the template but this is not best practice and it seems to break the template i.e. `parse error`
Note: The Bid in the template loops through the current bids made

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please include the view function responsible for receiving the POST.

Comment: @Lzak I have edited the question according to your recommendation. sorry for the delay and thanks